# Color glitch in notebook animated simulation

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation

I have this simulation of 'ducks' in a pond. Ducks are blue, and food is red. Food can be disbursed near the top or bottom of the pond. Ducks try to go to the nearest food. The first duck that gets there turns violet and stays stationary 'eating' the food for a number of time steps equal to the size of the food. This mostly works, except sometimes, all the ducks suddenly turn violet. Under some parameter combinations, they sometimes turn red. Color is determined by checking the state of each duck (blue if not eating, violet if eating) and setting a state value for the cell corresponding to its position (0=white=empty, 1=blue=non-eating duck, 2=violet=eating duck, 3=red=food).

I print all the grid state values as part of the plot title [update -- I replaced the numeric values with text, which allows an ASCII animation above the plot, with d=noneating duck, X=eating duck, and #=food], and can see that even when all the ducks turn violet, most of their states are 1, not 2. It makes it seem like it may be a matplotlib glitch, rather than a bug in my code (though that's still possible of course). I have tried rewriting the color coding, but I can't resolve the problem. I'm attaching the full script, which is meant to be run in an jupyter notebook. I would be grateful for any advice!

I've uploaded a movie of the simulator in operation in case you want to see this run w/o creating a notebook. You can retrieve it here (link takes you to ufile.io, an anonymous hosting site; file will be deleted automatically in 30 days): https://ufile.io/b0sqt4yk

```
import numpy as np
import random
import math
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import time

# Distance function
def distance(pos1, pos2):
    x1, y1 = pos1
    x2, y2 = pos2
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)

# Duck class
class Duck:
    def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
        self.unique_id = unique_id
        self.model = model
        self.eating = 0
        self.pos = (random.randrange(model.width), random.randrange(model.height))

    
    # Move function
    def move(self):
        possible_steps = [((self.pos[0] + dx) % self.model.width, 
                           (self.pos[1] + dy) % self.model.height) 
                          for dx in range(-1,2) for dy in range(-1,2)]
        possible_steps.remove(self.pos)
        
        # Get the duck-free steps.
        duck_free_steps = [step for step in possible_steps if self.model.is_duck_free(step)]
        
        if not duck_free_steps:
            return  # No place to move.
        
        food_positions = [food.pos for food in self.model.foods]
        if food_positions:
            nearest_food = min(food_positions, key=lambda pos: distance(self.pos, pos))
            
            # Filter the possible steps, choose only those that are duck-free.
            distances = [distance(step, nearest_food) for step in duck_free_steps]
            min_distance = min(distances)
            closest_steps = [step for step, dist in zip(duck_free_steps, distances) if dist == min_distance]
            
            if closest_steps:
                self.pos = random.choice(closest_steps)
        else:
            # If no food is available, move randomly.
            self.pos = random.choice(duck_free_steps)

    # Step function
    def step(self):
        if self.eating > 0:
            self.eating -= 1
            return
        food_at_pos = [food for food in self.model.foods if food.pos == self.pos]
        if food_at_pos:
            food_to_eat = food_at_pos[0]
            self.eating = food_to_eat.size
            self.model.foods.remove(food_to_eat)
        else:
            self.move()

# Food class
class Food:
    def __init__(self, unique_id, model, size):
        self.unique_id = unique_id
        self.model = model
        self.size = size
        self.pos = (random.choice(model.feeder_x_range), 
                    random.choice(random.choice([model.feeder_1_y_range, model.feeder_2_y_range])))

# Pond class (Model)
class Pond:
    def __init__(self, width, height, N, feeder1_rate, feeder1_size, feeder2_rate, feeder2_size):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.num_ducks = N
        self.ducks = [Duck(i, self) for i in range(N)]
        self.foods = []
        self.feeder1_rate = feeder1_rate
        self.feeder1_size = feeder1_size
        self.feeder2_rate = feeder2_rate
        self.feeder2_size = feeder2_size
        # self.feeder_x_range = range(15, 35)
        # self.feeder_1_y_range = range(1, 10)
        # self.feeder_2_y_range = range(40, 49)
        self.feeder_x_range = range(int(0.3 * self.width), int(0.7 * self.width))
        self.feeder_1_y_range = range(int(0.1 * self.height), int(0.3 * self.height))
        self.feeder_2_y_range = range(int(0.7 * self.height), int(0.9 * self.height))


        self.timestep = 0
        self.uneaten1 = 0
        self.uneaten2 = 0
        self.crossed_midline = 0

    def is_duck_free(self, pos):
        return all(duck.pos != pos for duck in self.ducks)

    def step(self):
        random.shuffle(self.ducks)
        for duck in self.ducks:
            duck.step()
        if self.timestep % self.feeder1_rate == 0:
            self.drop_food(self.feeder_1_y_range, self.feeder1_size)
        if self.timestep % self.feeder2_rate == 0:
            self.drop_food(self.feeder_2_y_range, self.feeder2_size)
        self.timestep += 1

    def drop_food(self, y_range, size):
        food = Food(len(self.ducks) + len(self.foods), self, size)
        food.pos = (random.choice(self.feeder_x_range), random.choice(y_range))
        self.foods.append(food)

    def plot_grid(self):
        grid = np.zeros((self.width, self.height), dtype=int)
        for food in self.foods:
            x, y = food.pos
            grid[x, y] = 3
        for duck in self.ducks:
            x, y = duck.pos
            grid[x, y] = 2 if duck.eating else 1
        return grid

# Parameters
pondwidth = 40
pondheight = 40
nducks = 50
rate1 = 4
rate2 = 8
size1 = 8
size2 = 8
model = Pond(pondwidth, pondheight, nducks, rate1, rate2, size1, size2)
timesteps = 50

# Plot function
def plot_grid(model):
    pond_grid = model.plot_grid()
    cmap = ListedColormap(['white', 'blue', 'violet', 'red'])
    plt.imshow(pond_grid.T, cmap=cmap, origin='lower', interpolation = 'none')
    plt.axhline(y=model.width / 2, color='grey', linestyle='--')

    # Counting how many ducks are closer to feeder1 and feeder2
    count_closer_to_feeder1 = sum(distance(duck.pos, (25, 5)) < distance(duck.pos, (25, 45)) for duck in model.ducks)
    count_closer_to_feeder2 = model.num_ducks - count_closer_to_feeder1
    proportion_closer_to_feeder1 = count_closer_to_feeder1 / model.num_ducks

    
    # Getting position and state of duck 1
    duck1_pos = model.ducks[0].pos
    duck1_state = "Eating" if model.ducks[0].eating > 0 else "Not Eating"
    duck1_eating = model.ducks[0].eating
    
    # Counting how many ducks are eating
    count_eating = sum(duck.eating > 0 for duck in model.ducks)
    
    # Calculating total uneaten food
    total_uneaten_food = sum(food.size for food in model.foods)
    
    # Calculating the sum of all duck states
    sum_duck_states = sum(duck.eating for duck in model.ducks)

    # concatenate duck states into a string
    duck_states_str = ''.join(str(duck.eating) for duck in model.ducks)

    # concatenate grid values -- giant string, but need for debugging color problem
    grid_values_str = ''.join(str(val) + ('\n' if i % pondwidth == (pondwidth-1) else '') for i, val in enumerate(pond_grid.T.flatten()))
    grid_text_str = grid_values_str.replace('0', ' ').replace('1', 'd').replace('2','X').replace('3','#')


    plt.title(f"Step: {model.timestep} Near source 1: {count_closer_to_feeder1} = {proportion_closer_to_feeder1:.2f},\
                \nUneaten={total_uneaten_food} Eating={count_eating} State sum={sum_duck_states}\n\
                {duck_states_str}\n\
                Uneaten near source1: {model.uneaten1}, Uneaten near source2: {model.uneaten2}\n\
                Ducks crossed midline: {model.crossed_midline}\n\
                Duck 1: {duck1_pos},{duck1_eating},{duck1_state}\n\
                {grid_text_str}", fontsize=10, fontname='Courier')


    # Adding a light blue border around the grid
    for edge, spine in plt.gca().spines.items():
        spine.set_visible(True)
        spine.set_linewidth(2)
        spine.set_edgecolor('lightblue')

    plt.xticks([])  # Remove x-axis ticks
    plt.yticks([])  # Remove y-axis ticks
    plt.show()
        
# Add sliders for parameters
rate1_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=rate1, min=1, max=20, description='Rate 1:')
rate2_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=rate2, min=1, max=20, description='Rate 2:')
size1_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=size1, min=1, max=20, description='Size 1:')
size2_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=size2, min=1, max=20, description='Size 2:')

# Modify the run_simulation function to continuously read the value from the rate1 slider
def run_simulation(change):
    global model
    model.timestep = 0  # Resetting the timestep
    with plot_output:
        for _ in range(timesteps):
            model.feeder1_rate = rate1_slider.value  # Update rate1 from the slider
            model.feeder2_rate = rate2_slider.value  # Update rate2 from the slider
            model.feeder1_size = size1_slider.value  
            model.feeder2_size = size2_slider.value  
            model.step()
            clear_output(wait=True)
            plot_grid(model)
            time.sleep(0.7)

# GUI Components
plot_output = widgets.Output()
start_button = widgets.Button(description="Start")
start_button.on_click(run_simulation)

display(widgets.VBox([start_button, rate1_slider, rate2_slider, size1_slider, size2_slider, plot_output]))
```